# ML.net ImageClassification predict the same value and during training metrics Accuracy is NAN

Tags: c#, machine-learning, ml.net, image-classification

I was trying to load FashionMNIST and train it throw model these are the classes of model

```
    public class DataImage
    {
        [LoadColumn(0)]
        [ColumnName("Image")]
        public byte[] Image { get; set; }

        [LoadColumn(1)]
        [ColumnName("Label")]
        public int Label { get; set; }

    }

    public class DataImagePredict
    {
        [LoadColumn(1)]
        [ColumnName("Label")]
        public int Label { get; set; }

        [LoadColumn(2)]
        [ColumnName(@"PredictedLabel")]
        public int PredictedLabel { get; set; }

        [LoadColumn(3)]
        [ColumnName(@"Score")]
        public float[] Score { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {

            return $"PredictedLabel : {PredictedLabel} Score {string.Join(",", Score)} ";
        }
    }
```

And this is code of training

```
 DataImage[] trainingData = FashionMNISTML.LoadTrainImages();


        DataImage[] testData = FashionMNISTML.LoadTestImages();

        var mlContext = new MLContext();

        IDataView trainingDataView = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(trainingData);

        IDataView testDataView = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(testData);

        trainingDataView = mlContext.Transforms.Conversion
                    .MapValueToKey("Label", "Label", keyOrdinality: ValueToKeyMappingEstimator.KeyOrdinality.ByValue)
            .Fit(trainingDataView)
            .Transform(trainingDataView);

        testDataView = mlContext.Transforms.Conversion
                    .MapValueToKey("Label", "Label", keyOrdinality: ValueToKeyMappingEstimator.KeyOrdinality.ByValue).Fit(testDataView).Transform(testDataView);

        var options = new ImageClassificationTrainer.Options()
        {
            FeatureColumnName = "Image",
            LabelColumnName = "Label",
            Arch = ImageClassificationTrainer.Architecture.ResnetV250,
            Epoch = 10,
            BatchSize = 10,
            LearningRate = 0.01f,
            MetricsCallback = (metrics) => Console.WriteLine(metrics),
            EarlyStoppingCriteria = null
        };

        var trainerPipLine =   mlContext.MulticlassClassification.Trainers.ImageClassification(options)
                                .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapKeyToValue(
                                        outputColumnName : "PredictedLabel",
                                        inputColumnName : "PredictedLabel"
                                    )) ;


        ITransformer model = trainerPipLine.Fit(trainingDataView);
```

the "FashionMNIST.LoadTrainingImages()" are just loops reading from the uncompressed file with have 60,000 for training images and 10,000 for test images ,
the problem is during training the model it prints

```
Phase: Training, Dataset used:      Train, Batch Processed Count:   0, Epoch:   0, Accuracy:        NaN, Cross-Entropy:        NaN, Learning Rate:       0.01
Phase: Training, Dataset used:      Train, Batch Processed Count:   0, Epoch:   9, Accuracy:        NaN, Cross-Entropy:        NaN, Learning Rate:       0.01
```

and according to this the predictions all are the same with score 0

I Have ML.Net last version and sciSharp.Tesnorflow version 2.3.1 because according to some issue was raised if i used the last version of tensor, this was the solution : to use version 2.3.1
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Do the class value score contain zero or the ToString() method returning zero?

Comment: @jdweng it return "PredictedLabel : 0 Score 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0"
as Console.WriteLine(PredictEngine.Predict(testData[i]).ToString()); i cause it is in for loop

Comment: Try : {string.Join(",", Score.Select(x => x.ToString("E0"))}

Comment: @jdweng it doesnt help as it is "PredictedLabel : 0 Score 0E+000,0E+000,0E+000,0E+000,0E+000,0E+000,0E+000,0E+000,0E+000,0E+000" and the predictions all still the same and accuracy in stil NAN